# Powershell Extracting sub string from string

Tags: windows, powershell

i have a String that either be network address or could be host name

```
$example1 = '\\192.168.3.3\s$\blabla\blabla\bla.txt'
$example2 = '\\srv\s$\blabla\bla.txt'
```

Im trying to test connection to the servers so i need only the \*****\ part.
$example1 = 192.168.3.3., $example2 = srv

im trying to use the -Match operation but im getting errors, can anyone assist?

Comment: Which match operation and which errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a quick solution:

```
$example1.split("\")[2]
```

Works for both IP address or host names.